# Scrapy can't access inner level data

Tags: json, python-3.x, scrapy

So here is the problem which is pretty basic Scrapy. I am scraping the following url for the json data
https://bama.ir/cad/api/search?vehicle=pride%2C151%2Cse&pageIndex=1
everything works fine and I can get to the first level tags, say key value pairs in 'metadata'
So far so good but I am gunning for the lower level value pairs say in `data[data']['ads']` and the yield doesn't work. The question is why and how to get it.

```py
def parse(self, response):
    data = json.loads(response.body)
    yield data['data']['ads']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are retrieving the information correctly. The issue is that the `data['data']['ads']` is a list, which is not one of the data types scrapy allows you to yield back.

The data types scrapy does allow include dictionaries, scrapy items, or scrapy requests.  So your a solution to your example could be as simple as wrapping the ads list in a dictionary, for example:

```
def parse(self, response):
    data = response.json()
    yield {'ads': data['data']['ads']}
```

Comment: Good man. One would think scrapy docs could bother to clarify these simple issues of type returns and such, but nope. Danke

Comment: It's mentioned in the api documentation for the `Spider.parse` method [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=yield#scrapy.Spider.parse)  but it certainly isn't very obvious or informative

Comment: Yes. they over simplify their examples while making the explanations "obvious or non-informative"